# COUNT(table_name.column_name) not giving accurate count. Am I applying GROUP BY on the wrong column?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions, product

I have a somewhat complex database structure running that tracks products. Here is a diagram of it generated by MySQL Workbench:

[image: Products Diagram]

Under this structure I have 3 products that I've added. All three of these products have the attribute `color` and an option of `red`.
I have a sql fiddle set up here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68470/4 displaying a query I'm running to try to get the `opt_count` column to say 3 on rows where the `attribute` column is `color` and the `option` column is `red`.

Nearly all the other `opt_count` values are wrong also, so I'm suspecting I am either not grouping by the correct column or I'm approaching this whole problem incorrectly.

How can I get the correct `opt_count` to show for each row?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what are you asking. Did you try to group by pvo.option?

Comment: Yes, also returned incorrect `opt_count`

Comment: Please add the desired output data what you want.

Comment: Can you describe what your query is trying to do?

Comment: `GROUP BY products.product_name, products.product_id,
 pvc.combination_id, pvc.combination`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, your schema is the problem as you have a many to many relationship (many products may have many options) which makes queries more difficult.

Here is a query that gives you the exact output you asked for.  It shows each option, how many unique products that option is assigned to (the COUNT(distinct product_id)) and provides a comma separated list of the product_id values that are assigned.

```
SELECT pvo.option, 
       count(distinct product_id), 
       group_concat(distinct product_id) products
  FROM (`products`)
  JOIN `product_variant_combinations` pvc using(`product_id`)
  JOIN `product_variants` pv using(`combination_id`)
  JOIN `product_variant_ao_relation` pv_ao using(`ao_id`)
  JOIN `product_variant_options` pvo using(`option_id`)
  JOIN `product_variant_attributes` pva using(`attribute_id`)
 group by pvo.option;
```

This is the output for red:

**red   *3* 111026,111025,111024**

See here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68470/133

You asked how to add attribute:

```
SELECT pva.attribute, pvo.option, count(distinct product_id), group_concat(product_id)
FROM (`products`)
JOIN `product_variant_combinations` pvc using(`product_id`)
JOIN `product_variants` pv using(`combination_id`)
JOIN `product_variant_ao_relation` pv_ao using(`ao_id`)
JOIN `product_variant_options` pvo using(`option_id`)
JOIN `product_variant_attributes` pva using(`attribute_id`)
group by pva.attribute, option
```

You must GROUP BY each non-aggregate expression in the SELECT clause.  In this case the two aggregate expressions are COUNT and GROUP_CONCAT, thus, you must GROUP BY pva.attribute, pvo.option

You probably want to find a good SQL tutorial on GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. How can I do this also with the attributes? example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68470/153 I want to see the attribute count next to the attributes there.

Comment: If you want the count of unique attributes assigned to a product, then don't GROUP BY pva.attribute, instead count(distinct pva.attribute)

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps

```
SELECT products.product_name
, products.product_id
, pvc.combination_id
, pvc.combination
, pva.attribute
, pvo.option
, COUNT(pvo.option) as opt_count
FROM (`products`)
JOIN `product_variant_combinations` pvc ON `products`.`product_id` = `pvc`.`product_id`
JOIN `product_variants` pv ON `pv`.`combination_id` = `pvc`.`combination_id`
JOIN `product_variant_ao_relation` pv_ao ON `pv_ao`.`ao_id` = `pv`.`ao_id`
JOIN `product_variant_options` pvo ON `pvo`.`option_id` = `pv_ao`.`option_id`
JOIN `product_variant_attributes` pva ON `pva`.`attribute_id` = `pv_ao`.`attribute_id`
GROUP BY 1
```

Returns:

```
| PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_ID | COMBINATION_ID |                                        COMBINATION | ATTRIBUTE | OPTION | OPT_COUNT |
|--------------|------------|----------------|----------------------------------------------------|-----------|--------|-----------|
|         Desk |     111025 |              4 |                  {"color":"Red","material":"Wood"} |     color |    red |         4 |
|         Lamp |     111024 |              1 |                                    {"color":"Red"} |     color |    red |         3 |
|      T shirt |     111026 |              6 | {"color":"Red","size":"Small","material":"Cotton"} |     color |    red |        18 |
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a `GROUP BY` clause, all non-grouped fields need to be invoked with an aggregate function (such as `max`, `avg` or `sum`) to tell the database how to aggregate them away for grouped rows.

Because you grouped by a single field and only specified an aggregate for one other your results are inherently unreliable and 'messy' - you're essentially getting random results based on the on-disk stored order of the found rows.

MySQL is the only RDBMS which doesn't enforce this requirement by default (it even [presents it as a feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)) - all other common databases like SQL Server, PostgreSQL and Oracle would throw a hard error on the query you wrote. Strict checking of this rule [can be enabled if you wish](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) but this will break many, MANY, badly written legacy applications.

Comment: sqllite allows it too :) (not that I'm defending it.)
In MySQL, set SQL_MODE=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to prevent it from allowing nonsense queries.

Comment: I linked to the documentation of that flag :) and yes, MySQL is the only DBMS which by default allows this SQL violation to my knowledge.

Comment: They are proposing to change that in the next major release, btw.  
I also just pointed out the exact flag because people don't read manuals in my experience. 

Proposal for changes:
http://www.tocker.ca/2014/01/24/proposal-to-enable-sql-mode-only-full-group-by-by-default.html

Answer (score 0):

There is some relationship between the group-by handling of MySQL and your question, but the problem really originates in the "combination row"

The group-by includes the combination row, which has a concatinated list. Group-by means that the database engine will create sets of data where the values in each column are identical.

Your combination column contains,

{"color":"Red","material":"Wood"}
{"color":"Red"}
{"color":"Red","size":"Small","material":"Cotton"}
{"color":"Red","size":"Medium","material":"Cotton"}
{"color":"Red","size":"Large","material":"Cotton"}

Those are all unique values, and thus cause the opt_count to be 1.

To get around this, you need to get an opt_count based just on color=red as a derived table, and then join that back into the tables that have the rest of the data you are interested in

I believe this query returns what you what you want. Note that you don't get one row back for each product, again because of the non-unique nature of your combination column.

```
-- Outer query to return the product/option/attribute information, plus the count from the derived table
SELECT
 products.product_name, products.product_id,
 product_variant_combinations.combination_id, product_variant_combinations.combination, 
 product_variant_attributes.attribute, 
 product_variant_options.option,
 red_products.option_count

FROM product_variant_combinations

INNER JOIN product_variants
  ON product_variant_combinations.combination_id = product_variants.combination_id

INNER JOIN product_variant_ao_relation
  ON product_variants.ao_id = product_variant_ao_relation.ao_id

INNER JOIN product_variant_options
  ON product_variant_ao_relation.option_id = product_variant_options.option_id

INNER JOIN product_variant_attributes
  ON product_variant_ao_relation.attribute_id = product_variant_attributes.attribute_id

INNER JOIN products
  ON product_variant_combinations.product_id = products.product_id

INNER JOIN
(
    -- Inner table to count the distinct products with the color "red"
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_variant_combinations.product_id) AS option_count,
      product_variant_attributes.attribute_id,
      product_variant_options.option_id
    FROM product_variant_attributes

    INNER JOIN product_variant_ao_relation
      ON product_variant_attributes.attribute_id = product_variant_ao_relation.attribute_id

    INNER JOIN product_variant_options
      ON product_variant_ao_relation.option_id = product_variant_options.option_id

    INNER JOIN product_variants
      ON product_variant_ao_relation.ao_id

    INNER JOIN product_variant_combinations
        ON product_variants.COMBINATION_ID = product_variant_combinations.COMBINATION_ID

    WHERE product_variant_options.option = 'red'
    AND product_variant_attributes.attribute = 'color'

    GROUP BY product_variant_attributes.attribute_id, product_variant_options.option_id
) AS red_products
    ON product_variant_attributes.attribute_id = red_products.attribute_id
    AND product_variant_options.option_id = red_products.option_id
```